# YouTube API How to resolve bad request error 400 PHP

Tags: php, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I am getting a 400 bad request error on my get request when using this code. Why is the GET request failing?

```
require_once 'inc/ggl/autoload.php';
require_once 'inc/ggl/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php';
require_once 'inc/ggl/src/Google/Client.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("API_Project");
$client->setDeveloperKey('{MY API KEY}');
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$videoResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet', array(
    'id' => '{ANY VIDEO ID}'
));

$vidtitle = $videoResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
echo $vidtitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The curly braces are not supposed to be included...